# How to reduce size of remote image without lost quality in android?

Tags: java, android, mobile

I'd like to know how to reduce remote images into android app without lost quality.
I've got some images in my websites with size: 500 X 400 and i'd like to load into app size 80dp X 60dp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) that can load image from website and supports various display options.